# Meaning of "at the way" in "she looked away from his face at the way his shoulders sloped"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please share with me how would you understand meaning of "at the way" in the context below.

> He smiled at her now and she looked away from his face **at the way** his shoulders sloped in the loose tunic he wore with the four big cartridges held in loops where the left breast pocket should have been, at his big brown hands, his old slacks, his very dirty boots and back to his red face again.

Comment: The Short Happy Life of Francis Macomber - Ernest Hemingway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She looked .. at the way (=how) his shoulders sloped. Not exactly the most concise of prose, but there you have it.

Comment: There is more than one part to this sentence:  1) she looked away from his face, 2) she looked at the way his shoulders sloped etc., 3) she looked at his big brown hands, his old slacks, his very dirty boots and, 4) she finally looked back to his red face again. It's just that "she looked" is not needed more than once. As I've said, it's a somewhat convoluted sentence, but the meaning should be clear.

Comment: Thank you very much Ingmar. I do apologize for deleting my comment.I thought it would be wrong if I ask it twice in this thread.thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

'At the way' in this sense means 'at the manner in which...'. You can also say 'at the way in which'. Whichever way it probably helps understanding if you add the 'in which'.